# How do I add guessed letters to an empty character array, making sure they're never overwritten?

Tags: java

Basically, it's for a hangman game and I initialize a guessed character char array of the same length of the word that's to be guessed, but without putting anything in the array. After each guess, I want to add the guessed character to the array, and it will check whether or not the character has been guessed, but I'm having difficulty implementing this.

What I've tried is having this helper method in my Hangman class:

```
private boolean checkIfGuessed(char c) {
        boolean guessed = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < guessedChars.length; i++) {
            if (guessedChars[i] == c) {
                guessed = true;
                break;
            }
            else if (guessedChars[i] != c && guessedChars[i] == 0) {
                guessedChars[i] = c;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < guessedChars.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(guessedChars[i] + " ");
        }
        return guessed;
    }
```

But it's not doing what I'd like, it simply fills the array with whatever letter is first guessed. (e.g. no matter where the game is, if the player guessed a first, and the array was of length 6, it would be aaaaaa)

I'm trying to do this by having a variable to flag if it's been guessed (and returning that to another method) and it's set to guessed if it loops through the array and finds the same character at some index that was initially guessed and will break out. Otherwise, if a certain index isn't equal to the character guessed, and it's equal to 0 (I know in numerical arrays, this signifies empty, not sure if in char arrays), meaning empty, it will write the guessed letter to the index the loop is at.

Problem being obviously it loops through and seems to label all the indices in the array to the first character guessed.

Is there a better way to do this/what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You add the character in a loop and don't exit the loop after you add it. Personally, I'd keep the guessed characters in a set. As it stands now, you'd need to scan the entire array, indicate if it was in the array, and add if it not.

Comment: @DaveNewton, that should be an answer.

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen I tend to avoid answering homework questions with actual answers since all I do is point in directions rather than provide implementation(s). Meh.

Comment: @Dave, I think you provided the right amount of information in your answer.  I would probably vote down a homework answer that provided full code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add the character in a loop and don't exit the loop after you add it. As it stands now, you'd need to scan the entire array (since it's unsorted), indicate if it was in the array by setting a flag or storing an index if found, and add it to the array if it wasn't found.

Personally, I'd keep the guessed characters in a set.

Comment: While I'm sure that's a great suggestion, our prof wants us to use character arrays in this assignment, so I'm trying to get on with those.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you use a [`HashSet<Character>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) instead.  You can just [`add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add%28E%29) and call [`contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) in a straightforward and efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

I would use two tables or arrays one for the guessed characters themselves
and another array that contains 256 elements corresponding to actual characters , and when the player picks a character, check the array containing 256 elements if the letter has been picked but first when making the 256 entry character array mark all letters which are NOT in the word with a 1 used as a flag to indicate that that letter is not available

when they pick a letter make sure they are picking a valid letter the flag should be 0 at first if they pick one that has not been picked before place a 2 in that location 
the index that you do the testing or placing to would be derrived from the Ascii value of the letters being picked , are you following me?
this is a very fast method of determining already picked letters as there are at most only 256 of them.... hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`BitSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) to store whether or not a character has been guessed.  The character's index (relative to `a`, or `A`) would serve as the index into the bit array.

This of course, assumes the 26-character English alphabet.  It might not be the best approach if you ever plan on localizing your Hangman game.

```
    private BitSet guessedChars = new BitSet(26);

    private boolean checkIfGuessed(char c) {
        return guessedChars.get(charIndex(c));
    }

    private void guess(char c) {
        guessedChars.set(charIndex(c));
    }

    private int charIndex(char c) {
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') return c - 'a';
        if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') return c - 'A';
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("char is not a letter");
    }
```